# How to fail a job and make it skip next attempts in the queue in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, queue

I'm writing a simple queue.

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\SomeMessageSender;

class MessageJob extends Job
{
    protected $to;
    protected $text;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($to, $text)
    {
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SomeMessageSender $sender)
    {
    if ($sender->paramsAreValid($this->to, $this->text) {
            $sender->sendMessage($this->to, $this->text);
        }
    else {
        // Fail without being attempted any further
            throw new Exception ('The message params are not valid');
        }
    }
}
```

If the params are not valid the above code will throw an exception which causes the job to fail but if it still has attempts left, it will be tried again. Instead I want to force this to **fail instantly and never attempt again**.

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you check in `paramsAreValid`? Because maybe you could that earlier on, and not even push the job in the first place.

Comment: The source code is just an example. Suppose the validation checks cannot be done in earlier.

Answer (score 20):

Use the [InteractsWithQueue](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Queue/InteractsWithQueue.html) trait and call either `delete()` if you want to delete the job, or `fail($exception = null)` if you want to fail it. Failing the job means it will be deleted, logged into the failed_jobs table and the JobFailed event is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the number of times the job may be attempted by using $tries in your job.

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\SomeMessageSender;

class MessageJob extends Job
{
    /**
    * The number of times the job may be attempted.
    *
    * @var int
    */
    public $tries = 1;
}
```